# uploading a file from local folder to firebase

Tags: c#, uwp, firebase-storage

I am having trouble uploading files(.mp3) stored in the local folder by user to firebase.
This is how a file is retrieved from local folder:

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

var songfolder = await folder.GetFolderAsync("Songs");

StorageFile mp3file = await songfolder.GetFileAsync(mp3fileforupload);
```

And this is how I create a stream file of the file and upload:

```
var stream = File.Open(mp3file.Path, FileMode.Open);

var task = new FirebaseStorage("-my-bucket-.appspot.com")
                       .Child("songs")
                       .Child(new_song_id)
                       .PutAsync(stream);

task.Progress.ProgressChanged += (s, f) => uploadProgress(f.Percentage);

var downloadurl = await task;
Debug.WriteLine("DOWNLOAD_URL " + downloadurl);
```

The file fails to upload. From the [Step-up-labs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiHlKH82pnSAhWlKsAKHe3dCv0QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fstep-up-labs%2Ffirebase-storage-dotnet&usg=AFQjCNF7tNDbgk1BORFtBF5gwgOiV0DdGA&sig2=bo6mUdN7a_7aTYIlzk-ljw) documentation, the file should be uploaded as a stream of a file. This worked when uploading files from the Assets folder, but does not work with files from local folder. I have tried uploading from the MostRecentlyUsedList but it still fails to upload. Any idea why this is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Step-Up-Labs C# Firebase-Storage API uses Stream for file uploads. Files should be uploaded as a Stream. What has worked for me is using a Memory Stream.

First I retrieved the file from local folder:

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

var songfolder = await folder.GetFolderAsync("Songs");

StorageFile mp3file = await songfolder.GetFileAsync(mp3fileforupload);
```

Then I read the bytes of the file using a DataReader:

```
byte[] fileBytes = null;
using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await mp3file.OpenReadAsync())
{
  fileBytes = new byte[stream.Size];
  using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream))
    {
      await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
      reader.ReadBytes(fileBytes);
    }
}
```

Then I used a MemoryStream for the upload:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);

var task = new FirebaseStorage("-my-bucket-.appspot.com")
           .Child("songs")
           .Child(new_song_id)
           .PutAsync(stream);

task.Progress.ProgressChanged += (s, f) => uploadProgress(f.Percentage);

var downloadurl = await task;
```

That did the trick. The file uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead to open the file

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder =
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile =
    await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(mp3file.Path);
var stream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: It works, but still not uploading even though it gets the file from the local folder. I think it has something to do with the streaming.